# How to prevent the loading of maps by default?

Tags: windows-phone-7, maps, bing-maps

I write own source class CustomTileSource : Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.TileSource.
In this class I'm return null value, but Bing map still loading, anybody know who to prevent map loading?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question fully, but if what you're trying to do is initialise a blank map without loading one of the default Bing Map tilesets, then you want to set the map mode to MercatorMode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mercatormode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't have VS to test now but try this:

```
map.Mode = new NullMode();
```